# adobe illustrator script that saves low quality pdf?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

How would one alter the preset script (Illustrator CC) or is there a script that can batch save a bunch of pdf's in low quality from some ai files? If anyone has such a script please add a link or include it in your response.

I tried the preset script and it did exactly what I wanted it to, saved a bunch of open ai files to pdf, but the result was too large.

[image: a screenshot of the adobe illustrator 'file' menu with the rollover of scripts and the submenu showing]

Comment: A bit of a tip, dont ask for "anybody knowing" because it opens you up for "yes, I know", which I do. Instead just ask "How would one", as its more explicit, which is good. Also instead of relying on a obscure "preset script" youd get more people answering if you specify which script explicitly. Relying on implication slows things down. Now the real remaining problem is that lower quality preset is unlikely to make smaller files for most illustrator documents, without sacraficing illustrator compatibility for a minimal gain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: First, select the preset that says "smallest file size".

Then, on the right hand side choose the "Compression" tab.

Set up your compression settings as follows:

[image: Example PDF compression settings]

Then save your image. Check the file size.  I managed to get a 1.83MB AI file, containing lots of raster images down to 343KB with those settings.  If that's not enough, reduce the resolution settings even more, or set the Image Quality to "Low". Reducing these will impact on the quality of any raster images quite severely, but that's the price you pay for keeping the file size low.

Of course if you have lots of raster images, you might not be able to get the file size down as low as I did.

After you have made these settings, you can save them as a preset.  Beside the Adobe PDF preset (at the top right of the dialog), hit the save icon, and name the preset so it will be available for other projects.